# an unheared missing word

Tags: homophones, listening

Somewhere, I have heard a sentence similar to:

> The main problem is the plagiarism **exosinated** by the Internet.

Instead of the meaningless bold word, what English similar word will make sense?

Comment: Depends what you think exosinated means. Could be encouraged, discouraged, popularized, facilitated, magnified, diminished etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the word you're looking for is ***exacerbate***:

> ***[exacerbate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exacerbate)***
>
> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> Make (a problem, bad situation, or negative feeling) worse.
>   *‘the exorbitant cost of land in urban areas only exacerbated the problem’*
>   *‘the strong pound has exacerbated the situation by making it much harder for UK companies to compete on price’*

So it would be:

> The main problem is the plagiarism **exacerbated** by the Internet.